# Android Studio Hedgehog spamming the same two warnings

Tags: android-studio, windows-8.1

I just installed the latest version of Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2 on my windows 8.1 laptop.

When I open my apps, the IDE keeps showing me

> "Could not determine abd version" and "Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b"

and it's spamming these indefinitely. I've tried leaving it for a bit to see if the error would resolve itself, but no.

It's unusable, because anytime I attempt to open a menu, says "File" to try and restart the IDE. It glitches out and I have to do the process again.

I've tried deleting ALL files associated with Android Studio, but once again the problem persists. I cannot do ANYTHING with it in this state.

Answer (score 0):

The Application Was Unable To Start Correctly (0xc000007b) is an error that either indicates some components required to start your game are missing, or that you have downloaded the wrong version (bit-wise) for your operating system.

Here is a few things to check:

Did you download the executable file (.exe) at an official website.

Or...

Did you download and run the correct file for your OS.

If error occurs, please try to uninstall and remove every related file to android studio and reinstall.

if nothing of the above worked try

```
you should follow these steps:

open Settings (just right-click on windows start and choose settings)

search for 'Windows Defender Settings' or just go to 'Update & Security' > 
'Windows Security'

then open 'App & browser control', in the new opened window scroll down to 
the end to find 'Exploit protection settings', click that

sort of settings will be shown and you can change the default settings. to 
create an exception you should click "Program settings" (which doesn't 
seem to be a button,but it is!)

click 'add program to customize', in the dialog enter your ide name.exe 
(you can easily find it by clicking 'open file location' on shortcut of 
 the application)

in my case the application name was 'phpstorm64.exe'
next you have to look for 'force randomization for images (Mandatory 
ASLR)' check the 'override system settings' and switch it off and apply 
settings.

I'm not sure if it's needed,but turning off 'Randomize memory allocations 
(Bottom-up ASLR)' stated to work for others
```

sources :
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly/9e070132-36b1-4e29-85cc-73365de5a4a5